# How to use exec() to construct multiple for-loops

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, exec

I'm trying to processing batchs with variable batch sizes. To do so, I attempted to construct multiple for-loops using exec(). However, it is seemed not supported by Python, as an error is reported: "unexpected indent".

The code is shown as follows, and the error occurs at the last line, which seems that the Python interpreter couldn't recognize the for-loop nested in function exec():

```
for b in range(num_loader + 1):
    exec("for i, batch_data in enumerate(data_train_loader%s):"%b)
        batch_data = batch_data.to(device)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the recognition problem through this way:

```
for b in range(num_loader + 1):
    exec("data_train_loader = data_train_loader%s"%b)
    for i, batch_data in enumerate(data_train_loader):
        batch_data = batch_data.to(device)
```

However, I got an new error which hints that data_train_loader is not defined. I check it through pdb, which show it did has a definition. Could anybody help me with that?

[error report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwnpm.png)